# How to check if end time and start time are equal with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays

I have a set of data which shows individual trip ID in the first column, their start time in 2nd column and their end-time third column.

The data are stored in SQL server and are generated using PHP fetch array while loop.

I like to know how can I use javascript to check if the start time in the first row is equal to the end time in the second row. I would like javascript to be able to print "FALSE" if it detects the end time and starts time are not equal. Can anyone advise? Thanks

[Image is the output I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9OEJ.jpg)

Below is my code:

```
    $tripdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($displaydate));
    $vesselcde = $vesselcode."%";

    $query_get_activity = " SELECT a.trip_id, b.start_time, b.end_time, c.activity_name FROM TRIP a JOIN ACTIVITY b ON a.trip_no = b.trip_no 
    JOIN ACTIVITY_TYPE c ON b.activity_id = c.activity_id WHERE trip_date = ? and trip_id LIKE ? ORDER BY a.trip_id";
    $params_get_activity = array($tripdate, $vesselcde);
    $stmt_get_activity = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_get_activity, $params_get_activity);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt_get_activity, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){

                                $tripid = $row['trip_id'];
                                $starttime = $row['start_time']->format('H:i');
                                $endtime = $row['end_time']->format('H:i');
                                $activitytype = $row['activity_name'];
                ?>          
                    <form class="form-inline">

                            <div class="timerows">
                                 <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="tripid"><?php echo $tripid;?></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" class="form-control mx-sm-3" value="<?php echo $starttime; ?>">
                                    <input type="text" name="start_time" id="end_time" class="form-control mx-sm-3" value="<?php echo $endtime; ?>">
                                    <!--<label for="activitytype"><?php echo $activitytype;?></label>-->
                                    <input type="text" id="checktime" value="TRUE">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </form>
                <?php                   
                    }

                ?>
```

Comment: Why not do this within the PHP loop, which creates the inputs. The values are in the variables already, just compare them and set the value as needed.

Comment: @Teemu Please read my question properly and click on the image to see how i want to compare the end time and start time. The one you are referring to is comparing start-time and end-time in the same row. What i want is to compare start-time in the first row and end-time in the next subsequent row.

Comment: My comment was maybe a bit poorly worded, I meant that the values are available. You can read the first row before the loop, and store the values to variables, it's just a small adjustment in the current code.

Comment: Notice also, that the PHP loop creates multiple elements with the same id, which makes the ids useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not much familiar with `php` but I am sure you can easily achieve this in `javascript`. This piece of code will help you to get your values in `javascript` which you may use in your code as per your use.

```js
function myFunction() {

var refTab = document.getElementById("ddReferences")
var  ttl;
// Loop through all rows and columns of the table and popup alert with the value
// /content of each cell.
var prev_val;
var new_val;
for ( var i = 0; row = refTab.rows[i]; i++ ) {
   row = refTab.rows[i];
   for ( var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++ ) {
      if ( j == 1){
           new_val = col.firstChild.nodeValue
           if ( new_val == prev_val){
                var x = document.getElementById("ddReferences").rows[i].cells;
                x[3].innerHTML = "True";
           }
           else {  
                var x = document.getElementById("ddReferences").rows[i].cells;
                x[3].innerHTML = "False";
           }
           
      }
      else if ( j == 2) {
           prev_val = col.firstChild.nodeValue
      }
      //alert(col.firstChild.nodeValue);  /// this is for showing value
   }
}

}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to alert the innerHTML of the cell in the table's row.</p>


<table id='ddReferences'>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td> 
      <td>6:20</td>
      <td>6:30</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>val2</td> 
      <td>6:30</td>
      <td>7:30</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val2</td> 
      <td>7:40</td>
      <td>8:30</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for great help. But i wan the TRUE or FALSE value to appear in the input text box instead of  , how can i do that?